# Add program to startup programatically in c++ without admin rights

Tags: c++, windows

Is it possible to add program to startup in c++ for current user without admin privileges?

One option would be to modify the registry, but that requires admin privileges.

The other option would be to put a symlink to: `%APPDATA%\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`. I tried to do this using the [filesystem library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs) like this:

```
fs::create_symlink("C\\Users\\example\\myapp.exe", "C:\\Users\\example\\Documents\\myapp.lnk");
```

However, unless I run the app as administrator I get:  `Invalid Arguments: Operation not permitted`

I also tried running the shell command from c++ like this:

```
system("mklink C:\\Users\\example\\myapp.exe C:\\Users\\example Documents\\myapp.lnk");
```

but it also failes without admin privileges.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: The third option (IMO the proper one) would be to create a Windows shortcut (.lnk) file in the user's %LOCALAPPDATA%\Roaming\\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying the registry doesn't require administrator privileges if you use the right path: `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` should be writable by an ordinary account.

Note `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` is not the same as `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` -- each has a list of startup programs, but the permissions are different, and the first isn't shared between all users.

Or, if you want to make a shortcut, determine the directory using [`ShGetKnownFolderPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/bb762188) and pass `FOLDERID_Startup`.  Do not try to build this path yourself -- the value Ken White provided will break on localized versions of Windows or if the user has customized their profile.

As with the registry, known folders `FOLDERID_Startup` and `FOLDERID_CommonStartup` have similar effects but different permissions, and the first affects only a single user.

Comment: The problem wasn't accessing the user startup folder. It was creating a symlink that requires administrator privileges. I guess I could craft the .lnk file myself and copy it to the user's startup folder. And I tried adding the entry to redistry under HKEY_CURRENT_USER and it worked. Thank you

Comment: @user3362334: A `.lnk` file (shortcut) and a symlink are not the same thing.  Shortcut-creation functions would have worked.